# Using a List in a where clause in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework-4, one-to-many, where-clause

I am trying to retrieve document id's over a one-to-many table. I want to use a List in the where clause to find all id's that are connected with every element in the list.

```
List<int> docIds = (from d in doc
                      where _tags.Contains(d.Tags)
                      select d.id).ToList<int>();
```

I know that the contains must be incorrect but I can't work it out. If I try a foreach I can't  work out how to check if the document contains all Tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that all `d.Tags` should be in the included in the `_tags` list, you can try:

```
List<int> docIds = (from d in doc
                      where d.Tags.All(t => _tags.Contains(t))
                      select d.id).ToList<int>();
```

If you want that `d.Tags` should contain all the item from `_tags` you need:

```
List<int> docIds = (from d in doc
                      where _tags.All(t => d.Tags.Contains(t))
                      select d.id).ToList<int>();
```

But I don't know how it translates to SQL by EF so maybe you need to evaluate it on the client site.

Comment: It was not clear from your question which list contains which so you maybe need to "reverse" the query to `_tags.All(t => d.Tags.Contains(t))`

Comment: Oh and it was the second one!

Answer (score 0):

Use a join:

```
List<int> docIds = (from d in doc
from t in tags
where d.Tags.Contains(t)
select d.id).ToList<int>();
```

Comment: a join doesn't actually work in this case, intellisense just screams at me in read that it won't work with the types. But thanks!