# Getting error when using a List in a where clause in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, list, lambda

Recently I read the following post [Using a List in a where clause in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034321/using-a-list-in-a-where-clause-in-entity-framework)

And I've tried to do exactly like that. In the example, we have the following code as **example**:

```
List<int> docIds = (from d in doc
                      where d.Tags.All(t => _tags.Contains(t))
                      select d.id).ToList<int>();
```

And here, we have **my** code:

```
List<PostOrcamentoServico> lOrcamentos = (from orcamento in db.PostOrcamentoServico
                                         where orcamento.Servicos.All(s => usuario.Clientes.Servicos.Contains(s))
                                        select orcamento).ToList();
```

However, I'm always getting this error:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Servicili.Models.Servicos'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

I already tried lamda, LINQ, etc.. but, nothing is working.

The idea is the following: PostOrcamentoServico is like a Budget, where must have one or many kind of services. 
On other side, the user logged, register specify all services that he can offer as professional. So, when he tries to search for budget, he can only search for budget of services that the user (professional) offer.

1. Budget -> One-Many-Services;
2. 2.Professioanl -> One-Many services;
3. Search = All budgets that has services in the Professional services list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Servicili.Models.Servicos` class has a unique identifier, then try this:

```
var servicios=usuario.Clientes.Servicos.Select(s=>s.Id);
List<PostOrcamentoServico> lOrcamentos = (from orcamento in db.PostOrcamentoServico
                                          where orcamento.Servicos.All(s => servicios.Contains(s.Id))
                                          select orcamento).ToList();
```

As the exception said you can't use the `Contains` method with non-primitive values. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported because they can be translated into SQL.That's way you need to convert your list of services(`usuario.Clientes.Servicos`) in a collection of an primitive type where you can identify all the services that you want to use to compare. If the `Servicos` class is an entity of your model, you should have a `Id` property:

```
var servicios=usuario.Clientes.Servicos.Select(s=>s.Id);
```

Comment: Servicos is list of services.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I read wrong, What you've written is the right way to fix that problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error description pretty much nails it: you are using a non primitive type in that Contains statement. The primitive type collections are required because entity framework knows how to translate them into an sql query, like so:

```
Select Name from Persons where City in ('Berlin', 'Paris', 'Rome');
```

Now imagine translating non-primitive collection.Contains() into an sql query like the above.

The solution is to build a list of, say, Ids and then use that list.Contains in your other queries, but of course, handing it an id parameter.

EDIT: pretty much like octavio said in his answer.